# Controlling Multiple HomePods

Tags: homepod

My school is thinking about getting smart speakers for each of its classrooms for various purposes.  It seems like the Alexa devices can be grouped into one account and controlled easily all from the same app/account.  Does Apple's HomePod offer the same kind of control for multiple devices?

Comment: PC or Mac........

Comment: Mac.  We have no PC's here...

Comment: OK, Pod might do the job

Comment: My question is more about how to control multiple HomePod units from a centralized control situation.